# calling class method from projects under same solution

Tags: c#

I have projects 1, 2 and 3 under solution A in visual studio.
Now there are few methods used by all the projects so I wanted to keep them separate.

I created a class file directly under solution A. How can I call the methods of this class?
This is how the code in class file looks. I want to access strSplit() method. Also this whole thing is under same solution. Is it possible to access it from another solution B?

```
using System;

public class Class1
{
    public Class1()
    {

    }

    public string[] strSplit(string x)
    {
        string[] array = x.Split(' ');
        return array;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to be using code from one project inside of another, you need to reference the other project (either via a project reference since they are in the same solution, or via it's compiled dll). Class files can't just exist under the solution and be used globally that way. A solution is essentially just a way to organize projects.

Comment: If you have code common to all projects, does it make sense to move it to one in particular, which you can then reference in the others? If not, it might make sense to make a third project as a class library with the common code. It's hard to say with the details we're given, as it's not a concrete example.

Comment: To be able to use a class it has to be part of an assembly. You can either add your codefile to each of the projects in the solutions via link (so that all projects use the same file) or you can create an extra assembly for such common code and add an assembly reference to each of the projects. I'd prefer the latter.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, it is best to include those files in a shared project that is referenced by projects 1, 2, and 3.  However, you can achieve what you are trying to do using linked files.

Given this file structure:

- Solution

  - Class1.cs
  - Project-1

    - Program.cs
  - Project-2

    - Program.cs
  - Project-3

    - Program.cs

For each of the projects right-click the project, select "Add", "Existing Item".

Navigate to the file (Class1.cs), and select "Add as Link" (use the little drop down to the right of the "Add" button, it will reveal a "Add as Link" action).

This creates a linked file within each of the projects.  Any changes to Class1.cs will be reflected in all 3 projects.  Each project will use the (current) version of Class1.cs during compilation.